# How to Unit testing my bot If I can't import Bot.Builder.Test branch was removed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, botframework

**(The branch of Test was removed from the Microsoft.Bot.Builder package - so can't inherit from DialogBaseTest without copying it manually)**

I have a RootDialog which is invoked when the user sends the first message.
The RootDialog invokes another dialog named: NameResolutionDialog, which presents a question to the user and then according to the user answer, returns a Contact object (I've created that object) to the RootDialog.

I want to write unit tests for my bot on VS.
I've looked at: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Tests
and couldn't really understand how should I start if I can't inherit from DialogTestBase without copying it manually (and all the other files in depends on) to my project...

Any other ways?

In addition do I need to test each dialog separately or should I test them together on each optional flow?

Thanks.